# Implementation of a Stack in C programming

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, pointer-arithmetic

I wanted to implement a stack using an array,but the compiler keeps showing me that there's an error in this line:

```
(f->(arr+(++count)))=value;
```

Error :

```
expected identifier before '(' token
```

Can I know what I have done wrong?

here's the code:

```
#define N 1000
typedef struct stack
{
    int arr[N];
    int tail;
}stack;
stack* insert(stack* f,int value)
{
    if(f->tail>N-1)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack OverFlow");
        exit(1);
    }
    int count=f->tail;
    (f->(arr+(++count)))=value; //Line that contains an error
    f->tail=count;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: You [probably] want: `f->arr[++count] = value;`

Comment: @FiddlingBits Your expression is just the address. I think you need to deref it: `*(f->arr + (++count)) = value;`

Comment: @CraigEstey Indeed.

Comment: But, you can replace three lines with just one: `f->arr[++f->tail] = value;`. But, I think you're skipping the first element (0), because you're _pre_-incrementing. So, the real fix is: `f->arr[f->tail++] = value;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean

```
int count = f->tail;
*( f->arr + count++ ) = value;
```

provided that initially the data member `tail` is equal to `0`.

Otherwise if for example initially the data member `tail` is equal to `-1` then you need to change the condition in the if statement the following way

```
if ( f->tail > N-2 )
```

and then

```
int count = f->tail;
*( f->arr + ++count ) = value;
```

Comment: Or use `f->arr[++count]` (or `f->arr[count++]`).  I'd use the array subscript notation automatically.